# Javascript hasOwnProperty(key) === false but property exists

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object called `context` and these logs:

```js
console.log({
  context,
  "Object.keys(context)": Object.keys(context),
  'context.hasOwnProperty("status")': context.hasOwnProperty("status"),
  "context.status": context.status,
});
```

Here's the output:

```js
context
  cache: InMemoryCache
  client: ApolloClient
  clientAwareness {...}
  forceFetch: false
  getCacheKey: f()
  status: 3
Object.keys(context): Array(5)
  0: "forceFetch"
  1: "cache"
  2: "getCacheKey"
  3: "clientAwareness"
  4: "client"
context.hasOwnProperty("status"): false
context.status: undefined
```

How can it possibly be that the `status` property is defined and has a value of 3, but "Object.keys", "hasOwnProperty" and accessing it indicate that it doesn't exist?

#### Update

Here's a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-roentgen-53ig2) with my code. If you open `./apollo/resolvers/bar`, you'll see the logs for the `context` object.

#### Update 2

I found out what was going on. The order of the fields in my GraphQL query was not correct, in that the resolver that was logging the context was defined before the resolver for `status`. See my answer below.

Comment: Can you show the code where you created context object???

Comment: did you ever hear of something called "prototype"?

Comment: @SriVenkataPavanKumarMHS it's part of a local resolver system built with Apollo Client. So the "context" object is created by the Apollo library

Comment: @ASDFGerte so somewhere down the line Apollo modifies the prototype but not the object?

Comment: I don't know, i am just saying that's one of the simplest ways to get this behavior. You could probably also do it in other ways, but you show zero code, so i can't tell.

Comment: @ASDFGerte let me create a CodeSandbox

Comment: The easiest is to analyze the object - look e.g. for `context.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("status")`, maybe it's there. Generally, look at the object in a debugger.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` as the name suggests only returns true of it is an own property. If you use `"status" in context` it should return true

Comment: If it's a property that comes from "prototype", it wouldn't have logged at first place right... tell me if am wrong...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jayakumarsharp/x0em4gb7/21/ check this one. If object contains then definitely it logs in the console. what is the issue here\

Comment: `context.status` logs `undefined`??

Comment: It turns out this was an issue caused by Apollo & GraphQL. Thank you everyone for your help :)

Comment: @ASDFGerte FWIW, `context.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("status")` returns `false` too. I'll try speak to the Apollo team to recommend printing a more intuitive warning for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was caused by a weird behaviour of Apollo.

In my GraphQL query, I defined `status` below the resolver where I was logging the values of `context`:

```
query Foo {
  id
  bar @client
  status @client
}
```

Moving `status` to the top fixes the issue:

```
query Foo {
  id
  status @client
  bar @client
}
```

Comment: But, how does `context.status` return undefined?

Comment: After moving `status` to the top, `context.status` returns the correct value, that is, 3. But when `status` was defined after `bar`, yes, `context.status` was undefined while printing the whole object included `status` as having a value of 3. Weird behaviour if you ask me.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your property is enumerable.
Respond  with more code where you are creating this object [See here][1]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` doesn't care about enumerability.

Comment: It doesn't have to be enumerable. That only applies to what `Object.keys()` returns

Comment: That's why I asked him to respond with more code.
What  he is  saying is not possible in normal scenario.